# How to logout from all providers in AWS Cognito?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito authentication in my web application. Users can authenticate using one of the three identity providers: cognito user pool (by username and password), facebook and google.
Here is how I get credentials:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
    Logins: logins
});
AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {
    console.log("Amazon Cognito Identity", 
    AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
});
```

logins - Object, that can contain tokens from cognito, facebook and google.

What should web application does if user click logout button?
I could do `userPool.getCurrentUser().signOut()` if current user is exists (current user is exists only in cognito username, password authentication)
But what should I do if somebody signs in using facebook or google?

Answer (score 1):

that is enough (the sign out), the session token will expire and that user won't be able to login again without using a new token. your cognito pool will still have the provider user.. but that is fine, if you remove it and the user signs in again, it will be a different user, so you need to keep the record in the cognito database

Answer (score 1):

The JS SDK has a method called clearCachedId that should wipe the local state and help with this.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html